Console attribute output is different when debugging and when running manually
I used the code from this example and changed it because I need to test the character grid.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void write_symbol_in_color(HANDLE h, SHORT x, SHORT y, const char* symbol, WORD color)
{
    COORD here = {0,0};
    here.X = x;
    here.Y = y;

    WORD attribute = color;
    DWORD written = 1;
    ::WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(h, &attribute, 1, here, &written);
    ::WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA(h, symbol, 1, here, &written);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Invalid handle");
        return 1;
    }

    write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 0, 0, "R", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 2, 0, "B", FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 3, 0, "C", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 4, 0, "M", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 5, 0, "Y", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    while (true)
    {
        write_symbol_in_color(hStdOut, 1, 0, "G", COMMON_LVB_GRID_HORIZONTAL|FOREGROUND_RED);
    }

    return 0;
}

When I start debugging in Visual Studio, I get a grid like in this screenshot (look at the G symbol):

But, when I start the program manually through clicking the .exe file, I get this output (no grid on the G symbol):

What is the problem? What do I need to do to get the character grid to display as it does when debugging in Visual Studio (with line\lines displaying)?
I tried to assign values to variables, but that didn't help.
Also, other line constants behave the same way, by that I mean when I add lines to the left, right, or below the symbol, they're not working if I run the program manually.

It's really hard to see any difference, if any at all, in the images. Can you please post larger, not as cropped, images? Perhaps change the console font size too?

And what happens if you only print one G? Do you still get the same problem?

@Someprogrammerdude If i print only G nothing changes. I resized the images, should now be easier to see

@Clifford the loop is only needed to keep the application from closing when running manually. By grid i mean the line above G and other possible lines around symbols, it is a part of the output attribute. COMMON_LVB_GRID_HORIZONTAL constant is responsible for the line above the symbol, but on manual startup grid(lines) part of the attribute doesn't work

I have run this code  and the COMMON_LVB_GRID_HORIZONTAL did not appear regardless of how executed.  What font/size have you selected, is this in Terminal or cmd?  I had Consolas 12 - perhaps that makes a difference? Anyhow I installed Windows Terminal and set that as the default console and it works either way.  So it is not a code issue but a Windows issue related to rendering the console, and so probably off-topic since how console apps are run is in the gift of the user not the developer.

"the loop is only needed to keep the application from closing when running manually."  I deleted the comment referred to (after I figured out the "grid" thing - funny term for a line!),  but the output need not have been in the loop, a Sleep() call would be a good idea though to prevent 100% core load.

@Clifford Yep sorry maybe it was a bit off-topic with c++ title

The loop could well be part of the issue. Just remove it and add a call to _getch() to prevent the console window from closing.

C++ was not the issue, just need not be in both the title and tag.  The code is C++, albeit only due to the use of scope resolution preventing C compilation.

Not a very satisfactory answer, but it appears to be related to the precise capabilities of the execution environment, so not entirely under your control as that is determined by the user/PC configuration.
It works in either case (in my case, YMMV) after:

Install Windows Terminal from https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n0dx20hk701

Configure Terminal as the default console:


I also set Command Prompt rather then Power Shell as the default, but that does not make any difference - your preference for default.


Then running from any of Explorer, Visual Studio, Cmd or PowerShell will run in Terminal and it appears to work the same regardless:

This does provide a work around if you can be sure Windows Terminal is installed (normally is in Windows 11 AFAIK), because Windows Terminal can be launched to execute a command so you could write a program, batch file or cmdlet to launch your program in Windows Terminal directly.  So if say your existing program is chargrid.exe, then a batch file in the same folder containing:
wt cmd /C cd %CD% && start chargrid

Will launch chargrid in its own Windows Terminal session.  You could equally write C or C++ code to spawn a wt session running chargrid.  It would be cleaner perhaps - but this is a quick-and-dirty solution as a demonstration.

Thanks! Now I have at least one way to make it work. But if it is possible i'd like to just change something in default Windows console or Windows configuration so the lines would draw

Agreed, but I doubt it is possible.  Different execution environments have different capabilities.  Windows Terminal is not a default install on Windows 10, not sure about 11.  Something I was aware of but not used to date. Just tried it in response to your question.

@slimebro_  Added a simple way to ensure the code runs in Windows terminal.
